# Add additional query parameters to the Azure B2C login url

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b, openconnect

I'm implementing Azure B2C to a .NET MVC app, and I need to add an extra query parameter to the login url.

Here's how I've set it up in the startup.cs

```
var openIdConnectAuthenticationOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,

                // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                },

                // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },

                // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = $"openid",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
            };

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
              openIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            );
```

And when someone tries to visit an [authorized] tagged page, it sends them to this b2c url:

https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_custom_signin&client_id=0000-000000-000-00&redirect_uri=https://localhost&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0

However, I need to add an extra query parameter onto the end, "&appId=000-000-000", so the resulting login URL is:

https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_custom_signin&client_id=0000-000000-000-00&redirect_uri=https://localhost&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0 **&appId=000-000-000**

how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you could not add the `appId` parameter, but I recommend to make use of the `state` parameter. You could use this parameter to send the value of appid as part of request and it gets returned back in response.

[image]

For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#1-get-an-authorization-code).

Comment: Thanks for replying - How do I set it in the state parameter in MVC? I'll give that a try. There is a b2c instance with a custom policy that needs that parameter, if I use javascript and manually append it, the b2c page loads, however, in MVC, without that parameter doesn't.

Comment: This is the sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420393/how-to-extract-state-parameter-from-openidconnect-token-response-in-net-core-mv